# How to use role based authentication in react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen there are many answers for this question. But here, my question and my existing code is different. I'm using following NPM module to route in my react application.

> import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

And this is the routing file of my application.
https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/241daafbc94df8543bced3695c7b7169

I want to use role base authentication system on this. All the roles are saved in the local storage and i need a way to check those when use goes to a route. I'm new to react. Please help me how to solve this.

Do I need to use separate file to get all the roles from local storage or can we do that inside the routing file ? Please advice

Comment: Great breakdown here https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Answer (score 3):

You can make Route custom components to handle the type of route. For example, if you have two Routes:

1) Admin Routes
2) Host Routes

then you will make one Component that will take the `role` as props and then using this component you will return the which route you need to render.

Small example is shown below:

```
class ResolveRoute extends React.Component {
   render () {
    const role = this.props.role
    return (
       {
          () => {
            if (roles === "admin") {
              <Route ...this.props />
            }
            else if (roles === "host") {
              <Route ...this.props/> // Render the routes that have host roles.
            }
            else {
              <Redirect to="/" /> // or Not found error page.
            }
          }
       }
    )
   }
}
```